# Python--how to extract information from a mixed of digits and characters and save them in a two dimentional list?

Tags: python

Data from a .txt:

```
ABC 12 34 24
edf 23 15 63
hre 41 3  356
...
...
```

I want to save each word(in the first column) in a set. For each element in the set, have a list that contains each number after it. E.G. word[ABC][1] = 34, word[hre][2] = 356.

I don't find any useful information about this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

mkt.py

```
words = {}
with open('a.txt') as f:
  for l in f:
    cols = l.split()
    word = cols[0]
    nums = [int(e) for e in cols[1:]]
    words[word] = nums

# Printing all words with their number lists
for k, v in words.iteritems():
  print("%s -> %s" % (k, v))

# Getting specific ones
print(words['ABC'][1]) # -> 34
print(words['hre'][2]) # -> 356

# Showing it's an int - doing some basic arithmetic operation
i = words['ABC'][1] + 50 # -> 84
print(i)
```

a.txt

```
ABC 12 34 24
edf 23 15 63
hre 41 3  356
```

Running:

```
$ python mkt.py 
hre -> [41, 3, 356]
ABC -> [12, 34, 24]
edf -> [23, 15, 63]
34
356
84
```

Comment: I want to keep these numbs int type. Should I add 'isdigit' or something in this line '(word, nums) = (cols[0], cols[1:])'?

Comment: Sure thing - see my edit. Just use `int` on each of the numbers.

Comment: this is handy. but i am using python 3.x. so i don't have dict.iteritems()

Comment: For Python 3.0 use `dict.items()` instead. See: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0

Answer (score 6):

You will need a dictionary mapping the keys to lists of integers:

```py
d = {}
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        d[items[0]] = map(int, items[1:])
```

Comment: How can I call those numbers then, say '356'?

Comment: @user1325302: Do you mean how to access them?  `356` can be accessed as `d["hre"][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to use generators to conserve memory even on large files.

Here I simulate the file using a multiline string.

```
file_ = """ABC 12 34 24
edf 23 15 63
hre 41 3  356""".splitlines()

rows = (line.split() for line in file_)
pairs = ((row[0], map(int, row[1:])) for row in rows)
d = dict(pairs)

for key_ in d:
    print key_, d[key_]

"""
>>>
hre [41, 3, 356]
ABC [12, 34, 24]
edf [23, 15, 63]
"""

print d['ABC'][1]
"34"
```